# What strategies (if any) do HR use to cope with the impact their decisions make on peoples lives and careers

Tags: human-resources

HR makes or implements decisions that impact on people, it's their role. PIP's, terminations, disciplinary measures etc,. all of these must have an emotional impact on the HR staff. What strategies can they use to cope with the stress. Is it best to view people impersonally without empathising and just shrug it off?

I have sacked people and had them on their knees crying, begging for another chance and I've found it upsetting because I know the guy won't get another job and he has a family to support. But I can deal with it because he stole MY money which is basically taking the food out of MY kids mouths, I own my business.

But professional HR people must deal with several of these scenarios every year and it's not their money. In my country with high unemployment HR are possibly a bit more lenient than some others because people have been known to end their lives over being sacked. So the decision can be very stressful for the people involved. I'm wondering how they cope with it, and if they either get inured over time or if there is a trend to change careers after a while.

Comment: It works be dehumanizing the people impacted. Not "employees" but human "resources".

Comment: Interesting question; would it be any different than, say, an auditor or infosec employee uncovering something (significant or insignificant) that causes a person to lose their job?

Comment: @Raystafarian I would think so, because of the constancy, rather than the rarity, and because HR has to deal with the person in their physical manifestation rather than their digital one. I can sack a remote worker without blinking an eye or my conscience bothering me at all.

Comment: *"HR makes decisions that impact on people: PIP's, terminations"* they actually don't. Except for the case of manifest disciplinary misconduct, all the rest are management's decisions that the HR department reports to the people in question.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco maybe in some places, others it's a HR decision, good point though, I've edited the question, because implementation is the important bit anyway.

Comment: @gnasher729 I trace the decline of the business environment back to the change of terminology from personel to "human resources".  Attitudes towards employees shifted to just what you are saying.  An employee went from being a person to a resource

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that employees don't take it personally when people steal from their company. And weirdly that employees are only fired for stealing. And just as weirdly that most of an HR person's job is firing people. Hardly any of an HR professional's job is firing people.

Comment: @DJClayworth just used stealing as an example, but if you want to read all that into it, go for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In larger companies, there is a very strong "Just following policy" vibe in HR. This is partly because it works to emotionally abdicate responsibility, since you can't do anything different anyways. That's a very old trick employed by various people throughout history when it comes to making people do things they may find to weigh on their conscience.

Ultimately though, it breaks down to not everybody can be HR. HR is looking out for the interests of the company, not necessarily the interests of the employees. When these align, great, but often times they don't.

It not being your money also makes it easier to follow a strictly defined procedure when handling firings - you haven't lost anything and firing someone is just your job, and that's that.

Ultimately its much of becoming accustomed to doing these things often.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense

Comment: @Kilisi I think the fact that it affects you so much is because its your business. You've been wronged there, and you're invested heavily in the outcome. If you do HR for a semi-large to large company, all you care about is protecting the company from lawsuits and following policy as appropiate.

Comment: No, it's not that. I feel sorry for the person, I struggled to feed just myself many times in my youth and now I'm a family man I can easily imagine how badly I would feel if I couldn't support my wife and kids and I know the chances of them getting another job are very slim. I can look at a labourer and put myself in his shoes, because I've worn those shoes. I know his troubles.

Comment: Not everybody has that level of empathy. And people who go into fields like this with that level of empathy quickly learn to supress it as part of the job.

Comment: In some cases it can be the same ki d of professional detachment surgeons sometimes have to cultivate. You're injuring someone, but for a greater good. Maybe even their own good, if the problem is of their own creation; some folks learn only when shown they _can't_ get away with ignoring advice. Firing for cause is more common than layoff in most businesses.

Answer (score -7):

Given the behaviour of most corporate HR, I have a gut feeling they actually like firing people.

Atleast where I work, they do random stuff like fire 10% of the company, then hire people with similar skillsets but at 50% higher salaries. Or they will implement stack ranking, fire the bottom 5%, not be able to find more people to replace those 5% and then increase the workload of the people still with the company. When that doesnt work out, they go and hire people who are worse than the 5% that were fired.

Now, as per policy people cannot be fired for performance reasons before 1 year is completed, and so in the upcoming round of stack rankings, they fire the bottom 5% of the remaining 95%..  instead of the actual low performers.

If they actually had a negative impact personally due to firing people..  such behaviour would not occur.

Comment: Sounds insane, although it might be something similar to when they rewarded social workers with bonuses for finding breaches and suddenly breaches went up about 5000% until they stopped rewarding.

Comment: HR doesnt create these policies, upper management does. HR just implements them, and when you got a comfortable gig playing it by the book, why not.

Comment: Reminder: it usually isn't HR making the hiring and firing decisions.

Comment: You clearly know nobody who has worked in HR. Don't write about stuff you don't know.